# How do mind transfers interact with soul loss?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I'm interested in stupid, over-the-top combinations. I very nearly LARPed a vampiric Ulitharilich. However, in Pathfinder this isn't actually possible, because pathfinder is sane about templates and archetypes.

However.

- A proper, self-respecting Ilithid is a psion telepath. At some point, they should get [True Mind Switch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/m/mind-switch) (Or [this](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:True_Mind_Switch)).
- If they aren't actually proper, got into necromancy, and became a lich. Their soul is now in their phylactery.
- Get a vampire to create a spawn out of an Illithid, then kill the vampire
- Mind Switch into the vampiric Illithid.

Are you now both a lich and a vampire? Do you have flesh? How do you reform if you die?

Comment: Is there something like *true mind switch* for *Pathfinder* to which you can link? Otherwise, this might need to be tagged *D&D 3.5*--opening a whole 'nother can of shenanigans. ("Shenanigans! Now in *cans!*")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Answers

- **Are you now both a lich and a vampire?** No, you don't exist because there aren't illithids in *Pathfinder*. Also, no, because undead creatures are immune to mind-affecting effects, making the power *true mind switch* unable to target either the illithid lich or the illithid vampire.
- **Do you have flesh?**  Yes. An illithid has slimy flesh. A lich has withered flesh. A vampire has cold flesh. So if--somehow--this combination succeeds, the end result would likely be the cold, slimy flesh of the vampire illithid instead of the previously slimy, withered flesh of the lich illithid.
- **How do you reform if you die?** The text of the power *true mind switch* explains that the last body a creature inhabits is its "true" body. The phylactery would likely recreate that one.

More details below.

## The Scheme Has Issues

There are several. I'll address them in the order they appear in the question.

> A proper, self-respecting illithid...

...doesn't exist in *Pathfinder.* [Illithids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illithid) were one of a handful of creatures--including [beholders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beholder_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)) and [yuan-ti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuan-ti)--that Wizards of the Coast decreed *Dungeons and Dragons* product identity (somewhat after-the-fact in some cases, leaving a few publishers who had published books about such creatures forced to destroy remaining copies, if I remember correctly). They aren't part of the [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/index.htm), and no one can include them in their games without permission without risking reprisal, the same way you can't include in your game vulcans or hobbits. You can read more about this [here](http://forum.rpg.net/archive/index.php/t-586958.html?s=2a7d19955c8f04b2eb001ed77d330422) and [here](http://wesschneider.tumblr.com/post/75291061040/wes-ive-been-playing-pathfinder-for-little-over-3).

> ...is a psion[, most likely a] telepath.

Okay. Sure. That's a reasonable choice for an illithid.

> At some point, [it] should get [the power] *true mind switch*.

So if 17 levels of *Pathfinder* [telepath](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/psion) gets stapled onto the typical mind flayer from the *Monster Manual* for *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*--which is what must be used because there is no *Pathfinder* mind flayer--that mind flayer should be expected to take this specific power. Also, so we're clear, that's a CR 25 creature, appropriate as a boss battle for a party of level 20 *Pathfinder* PCs. ([Epic level play](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement) isn't supported directly by Paizo.)

But fair enough.

> [Then the illithid got] into necromancy and became a lich. [Its] soul is now in [its] phylactery.

Assuming [psionics-magic transparency](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers), an illithid telepath 17 could certainly create a phylactery if it meets the requirements, granting it the template [lich](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/lich). This however, changes the illithid's type from [aberration](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations) to [undead](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead). This change is *really* important.

> [The illithid then gets] a vampire to create a spawn out of [another] illithid then [the first illithid kills] the vampire.

I can concoct a scenario in which cunning, vicious illithid might convince bumbling vampire to turn lackwit illithid into a vampire, and afterward kill bumbling vampire. The underdark's a wretched hive of scum and villainy. But mechanical problems remain.

An illithid in *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* is an aberration, and that game's vampire template excludes aberrations from gaining the template [vampire](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/vampire.htm), restricting the template to humanoids and monstrous humanoids as per the SRD. (Other texts modify this, but let's keep it simple.) *Pathfinder*'s template [vampire](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/vampire) isn't restricted in the same way, allowing aberrations to become vampires. So if mind flayers in a *Pathfinder* game were not sufficient evidence of house rules, illithid vampires are certainly sufficient evidence the DM is mixing systems and making up stuff. (You should ask what *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* things are available to PCs.)

(Also, a [vampire spawn](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/vampire/vampire-spawn) is a specific kind of creature created by vampires from low Hit Dice creatures; those Hit Dice are exceeded by the mind flayer. Hence I'm pretty sure a mind flayer who becomes a vampire would become a free-willed vampire. And, in all likelihood--unless the plan's been cleared with him first--an *angry* free-willed vampire.)

> [The illithid lich uses the power *true] mind switch* [and transfers his consciousness and soul] into the vampire illithid.

The big problem here is the power [*true mind switch*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/m/mind-switch) is mind-affecting and both the lich illithid and the vampire illithid are immune to mind-affecting effects because they're undead.

There's at least [one way](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard/archetypes/paizo---bard-archetypes/dirge-bard) around this, and I'm sure there are others, too, but this creature is CR 25 *before* trying to become a lich vampire illithid. Giving him more class levels just makes him more unlikely to ever see play.

Finally, *Pathfinder* is very clear about what abilities one gains when one switches bodies using the power [*true mind switch*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/m/mind-switch) (unlike the *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* [version of the same power](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/mindSwitchTrue.htm), which reads like it was never designed to see play) and excludes the fun stuff like spell-like and supernatural abilities. I guess the lich illithid that manages to pull this off might end up with slightly better statistics and the ability to *spider climb*, but that's a *really* convoluted set up for relatively minor gain.

Comment: Wouldn't they at least have sweet-ass restrictions (Shadowlessness, requiring invitations..)?

Comment: Well, would this work in D&D?

Comment: @Glycan For questions like yours, it's usually better to ask about the the *result* than about the scheme. I'm pretty sure no one took a crack at this question for a while because the *scheme* was so specific and unwieldly. Were you to have asked, "Can a mind flayer be both a lich and a vampire?" and left it at that, I could've pointed out the no-mind-flayers-in-*Pathfinder* thing in a comment, the question would've gotten the *D&D 3.5* tag, and more folks would've been willing to help.

Comment: @Glycan In *D&D 3.5* the scheme requires a lot more research to achieve, but--with a DM who allows every book--undoubtedly it's possible. I'm pretty sure everything possible *somehow* in *D&D 3.5.*

Comment: Conventional wisdom says that both are templates that can be applied to living creatures only, so the obvious answer would be no.

Comment: Also, aren't most portrayals of lichs skeletal?

Comment: @Glycan The use of the *D&D 3.5* power *true mind switch* and spell *polymorph any object* spit in the face of  wisdom, common sense, *and* game balance. Further, lich depictions are... inconsistent. Although the *Monster Manual* refers to them as skeletal, it then provides an illustration of one as withered. However, given most liches' power levels, they can probably *appear* however they want using spells... if they care.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. Could you explain what's so bad about these spells?

Comment: @Glycan These are better asked as their own questions, but to see what has come before, start [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/19565/8610) and [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/18410/8610).