# Do Dragonwrought Kobolds Incur Age Penalties if They're Not True Dragons?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters

I was just wondering if the question on [whether Dragonwrought Kobolds are true dragons or not](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/17144/is-a-dragonwrought-kobold-a-true-dragon) have any bearing on whether or not they get age penalties to their physical stats? Please back up your answers with rule quotes and citations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## No, they do not, and true dragon status has no impact here

*Races of the Dragon* explicitly states that dragonwrought kobolds do not incur penalties for aging. See the footnote on page 39:

> Ability penalties due to aging do not apply to dragonwrought kobolds.

True dragon status affects **very** few things in the game: Eberron’s sovereign archetypes and dragon psychoses are the only things that I am aware of that care about the distinction. At least a couple of those are **very** powerful, though, which means it does matter for some.

Comment: The fact that this is something they explicitly wrote, rather than being a funny twist of the rules, a weird combination of disparate books, as one might expect, kind of frightens me. Though it *is* nice to be able to answer a question on dragonwrought kobolds without writing not one but *two* treatises.