# Does a Dragonwrought Kobold gain Dragon attacks?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, dragons, kobold

The Kobold only feat “Dragonwrought” turns you into a True Dragon with a colour/metal of your choosing. Does this mean it also gets the attacks associated with being a true Dragon? i.e. Breath Weapon, and all the natural weapons?
And, if yes, would it get these weapons based on its age or its size? i.e. would a Great Wyrm Bronze Dragonwrought Kobold get the breath weapon of a Great Wyrm Bronze Dragon, or a small BronzeDragon (which is a Wyrmling)?

Answer (score 4):

No.

Whether or not dragonwrought lets you *count as* a true dragon is [contentious](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/17144/4563), but even if it lets you *count as* a true dragon, its only mechanical effects are those listed in the feat, the statements made in the corresponding chapter in *Races of the Dragon*, and things that *require* being a (true) dragon.

The particular attacks found in various species of dragon are features of *that particular creature*, not things that you get as soon as you meet some “true dragon” requirement. The *Monster Manual*’s “Dragon, True” entry can be misleading on this point, but ultimately the features described at the top of that section about bites, claws, wings, tail slaps and sweeps, crushes, breath weapons, frightful presence, spells, and so on are just a kind of *short-hand*—describing things common to the creatures in that section once, rather than repeatedly.

So a red dragonwrought kobold may count as a “version” of red dragon, to use *Races of the Dragon*’s wording, but it has no entry in the *Monster Manual* red dragon’s entry, because it isn’t one of the twelve creatures (wyrmling red dragon, very young red dragon, etc.) described in that section. Thus, it gets none of those benefits. It gets the benefits laid out in *Races of the Dragon* for dragonwrought kobolds in general, and it counts as a (true, arguably) dragon for requirements and prerequisites. Nothing else.