# Is a Dragonwrought Kobold's offspring a Dragonwrought, a Half-Dragon, or a normal Kobold?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, lore, races, dragons, kobold

[Is a Dragonwrought Kobold a True Dragon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/17144/is-a-dragonwrought-kobold-a-true-dragon) gives arguments for and against dragonwrought kobold being a "True Dragon". For this question, I assume that dragonwrought kobold is a dragon as stated in one of the answers.

Half-Dragon is crossbreed offspring of dragon and non-dragon creatures.

**Is dragonwrought kobold offspring a half-dragon of the same type as its dragonwrought  parent?**

In particular, does union between dragonwrought kobold and normal kobold produce dragonwrought kobold or half-dragon kobold or normal kobold? To take it further, what is the result of union between (polymorphed?) dragonwrought kobold and (for example) human?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Races of the Dragon* certainly indicates that dragonwrought kobolds are rather rare in kobold populations. It does not appear that they breed true.

Moreover, *Races of the Dragon* defines both dragonwrought kobolds and half-dragons as “versions” of full dragons. But the parent of a half-dragon is the full dragon. Even if a red-dragonwrought kobold or a red half-dragon are “versions” of a red dragon, even if they count as a form of “true dragon,” the parent of a red half-dragon is a red dragon—not any other “version” of it. So the offspring of dragonwrought kobolds (and half-dragons) is not a half-dragon.

The fact that the half-dragon template is much stronger than the Dragonwrought feat, and offers numerous dragon-y features that dragonwrought kobolds lack, is another strong reason to believe dragonwrought kobolds do not give birth to half-dragons (barring a full dragon mate).

Thus, the most common progeny of a dragonwrought kobold seems likely to be regular kobolds, though dragonwrought kobolds are presumably more likely for them than for other kobolds. Perhaps a mating pair of dragonwrought kobolds would be able to reliably produce more dragonwrought kobolds. I do not believe that *Races of the Dragon* addresses the point directly.

As for half-dragons, since I brought them up: the draconic template in *Races of the Dragon* is most likely the best choice for the offspring of half-dragons (assuming the other parent is not a dragon of any kind).